# Having problems running nodeBB with redis on windows7

Tags: node.js, mongodb, redis, nodebb

I install redis on win7 by exe and I got nodeBB on
there are some first time config prompt and then
nodeBB even start populating database with default config.

After entering admin name email pwd, I got stuck here as below:

> c:\Users\kaeyonbaker\Downloads\NodeBB-master\NodeBB-master\node_modules\redis\in
>   dex.js:535 throw err; ^ TypeError: Object # has no method 'genSalt' at
>   Object.User.hashPassword
>   (c:\Users\kaeyonbaker\Downloads\NodeBB-master\No
>   deBB-master\src\user.js:555:10) at
>   c:\Users\kaeyonbaker\Downloads\NodeBB-master\NodeBB-master\src\user.js:13
>   3:11 at try_callback
>   (c:\Users\kaeyonbaker\Downloads\NodeBB-master\NodeBB-master\
>   node_modules\redis\index.js:532:9) at RedisClient.return_reply
>   (c:\Users\kaeyonbaker\Downloads\NodeBB-master\No
>   deBB-master\node_modules\redis\index.js:614:13) at ReplyParser.
>   (c:\Users\kaeyonbaker\Downloads\NodeBB-master\Nod
>   eBB-master\node_modules\redis\index.js:266:14) at
>   ReplyParser.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17) at
>   ReplyParser.send_reply
>   (c:\Users\kaeyonbaker\Downloads\NodeBB-master\Node
>   BB-master\node_modules\redis\lib\parser\javascript.js:300:10) at
>   ReplyParser.execute
>   (c:\Users\kaeyonbaker\Downloads\NodeBB-master\NodeBB-
>   master\node_modules\redis\lib\parser\javascript.js:189:22) at
>   RedisClient.on_data
>   (c:\Users\kaeyonbaker\Downloads\NodeBB-master\NodeBB-
>   master\node_modules\redis\index.js:488:27) at Socket.
>   (c:\Users\kaeyonbaker\Downloads\NodeBB-master\NodeBB-m
>   aster\node_modules\redis\index.js:82:14)

Then i change redis into mongo and i've got the similar error as below:

> c:\Users\kaeyonbaker\Downloads\NodeBB-master\NodeBB-master\node_modules\mongodb\
>   lib\mongodb\connection\base.js:242 throw message; ^ TypeError: Object#
>   has no method 'genSalt' at Object.User.hashPassword (c:\Users\kaeyonbaker\Downloads\NodeBB-master\No
>   deBB-master\src\user.js:555:10) at
>   c:\Users\kaeyonbaker\Downloads\NodeBB-master\NodeBB-master\src\user.js:13
>   3:11 at
>   c:\Users\kaeyonbaker\Downloads\NodeBB-master\NodeBB-master\src\database\m
>   ongo.js:418:5 at
>   c:\Users\kaeyonbaker\Downloads\NodeBB-master\NodeBB-master\node_modules\m
>   ongodb\lib\mongodb\collection\core.js:703:14 at
>   c:\Users\kaeyonbaker\Downloads\NodeBB-master\NodeBB-master\node_modules\m
>   ongodb\lib\mongodb\db.js:1098:5 at
>   c:\Users\kaeyonbaker\Downloads\NodeBB-master\NodeBB-master\node_modules\m
>   ongodb\lib\mongodb\db.js:1806:9 at Server.Base.callHandler
>   (c:\Users\kaeyonbaker\Downloads\NodeBB-master\No
>   deBB-master\nodemodules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\connection\base.js:442:41)
>   at
>   c:\Users\kaeyonbaker\Downloads\NodeBB-master\NodeBB-master\node_modules\m
>   ongodb\lib\mongodb\connection\server.js:485:18 at MongoReply.parseBody
>   (c:\Users\kaeyonbaker\Downloads\NodeBB-master\NodeBB
>   -master\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\responses\mongo_reply.js:68:5)
>   at null. (c:\Users\kaeyonbaker\Downloads\NodeBB-master\NodeBB-mas
>   ter\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\connection\server.js:443:20)

Comment: Could you rewrite your questions and make it more readable please?

Comment: Try the latest NodeBB, they may have fixed it already.